# Proving $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{1+ a_n}$ diverges provided $\sum a_n$ diverges and $(a_n)$ is decreasing and nonegative

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone tell me why this might a wrong solution? The solution looked nothing like mine

Let $t_n$ be the partial sums of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{1+ a_n}$

$$t_n = (1-\frac{1}{1+a_1}) + (1-\frac{1}{1+a_2}) + \dots + (1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}) \\ \geq (1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}) + (1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}) + \dots + (1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}) \\ \geq n - \frac{n}{1+a_n} \geq n$$

So $n \to \infty$ shows that the partial sums are unbounded

Comment: Why is the last inequality true?

Comment: Because $\frac{n}{1 + a_n}$ is a positive number

Comment: But that makes $n - \dfrac{n}{1+a_n} < n$.

Comment: If $\frac{n}{1+a_n}$ is positive that means that the

$$ n - \frac{n}{1+a_n} \leq n$$

Comment: Hi @sidht, but $n - (\text{a positive number})<n$, right?

Comment: Oh shoot...you guys are right...

Comment: I have asked this before.

Comment: I saw this question a few days ago.  I don't think $(a_n)$ even needs to be decreasing.  The suggeston there was to look at two cases: (i) $a_n \leq 1$ for all $n$; and (ii) $a_n > 1$ along a subsequence. This is probably easier than your approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a_n$ is decreasing and positive, then there exists $M>0$ such that $0<a_n<M$ for all $n$.

Then $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\ge \frac{a_n}{1+M}$ and therefore the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ diverges.

Comment: This is a one-line proof...amazing compare to the one I am reading!

Comment: Actually one can prove that if $a_n$ is positive, then $\sum  \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges if and only $\sum a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

The final inequality that you've typed above is incorrect: $n-\frac{n}{1+a_n}\leq n$ since $\frac{n}{1+a_n}\geq 0$ as noted in the comments.

Comment: Is it still possible to continue with what I have?

Comment: Hi @sidht, see the answer by Pocho la pantera ...