# Does the transformation $a_n \leadsto \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ unconditionally preserve divergence of a series?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\sum{a_{n}}$ is divergent, prove that $\sum\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}}$ is divergent.

Is this always true? Because I found in the books this is just when $a_{n}>0$, and when I use $a_{n}=(r_{1},r_{2},-1,r_{4},-1,...)$, can we still say that the second series is divergent? Where $r_{i}$ can be any real such that $(a_{n})$ converges to zero. (The position of the $-1$ doesn't matter, it is just there to make the second series not defined).

Comment: But $a_{n} = (1)$ isn't divergent, is it? - so you haven't found a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry it was -1. So the sequence is not even defined, that was my question if we can consider that case as divergence.

Comment: $a_n = (-1)$ isn't divergent, is it?

Comment: Are we given that $a_n$ are all positive?

Comment: -1-1-1-1 goes to -infinity

Comment: Series, not sequence, @Clarinetist!

Comment: Oops, thanks @TedShifrin!

Comment: @JorgeRamos The question is undefined if any $a_n=-1$.

Comment: you are right, my mistake but consider a sequence that goes to zero, but has -1, everywhere then.

Comment: $a_{n}$ could be any real.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480931/proving-sum-n-geq-1-fraca-n1-a-n-diverges-provided-sum-a-n-diverg .

Comment: @JorgeRamos You can't have $(a_n)=(r_1,r_2,-1,r_4,-1,\ldots)$ because then some $n$ has $a_n=-1$ and so $-1/0$, an element of the partial sum, is *undefined*. The question is undefined if *any* $a_n=-1$.

Comment: That was my question, more like a philosophical question, because the definition of converge of series says that if the limit exist and is finite, but that would imply that if the limit doesn't exist the series not convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not always true. Let us take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. The series $\sum a_n$ obviously diverges, but $$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=a_n-a_n^2+O(a_n^3)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right),$$ so $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n < 1$,
$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
> \frac{a_n}{2}
$.
If $a_n \ge 1$,
$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
\ge \frac{1}{2}
$.
The sum of either of these diverge.

Comment: If a_n <0 , a_n/(1+a_n) > a_n/2 is not always true. I think you are assuming a_n >0